# Increase Bestsellers Report limit Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, reports

I'm trying to increase the report limit of the Reports > Product > Bestsellers and Reports > Customers > Customers by order total. Default is set to 5 max.

Now I thought this was done by editing the $_ratingLimit value from (5) to (whatever) (Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Report_Bestsellers_Collection), but this doesn't work for me.

Anyone have the quick fix?

Thanks

Comment: See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/m/viewthread/35055/#t249065

Comment: That's why I said, changing the $_ratingLimit doesn't work in Magento 1.7.

Answer (score 3):

You can change it in: /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Report/Bestsellers/Collection.php

After making the change (or after creating the new file in /app/code/local), make sure to do the following:

- Re-run the compilation process (System -> Tools -> Compilation)
- Clear Cache
- Refresh Statistics (Reports -> Refresh Statistics)

Worked for me on CE1.7